# WMS layer is not showing the colors associated with the dataset in ArcGIS JavaScript 4 SDK

Tags: wms, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, getmap

This WMS layer I loaded into ArcGIS JS 4 SDK is not loading correctly. I tried to include a customParameters object, but I don't think I wrote it correctly since the documentation isn't super clear. I was only able to get it to show black where the data should be. Can anyone provide some insight?

The code below is trying to recreate [this](https://coastwatch.noaa.gov/cw_html/cwViewer.html?lat=27.00&lon=-80.80&z=3&date=20231002&layer0=basemapWI&layer1=ghrsstBlendedOSPOd) website.

```
    "esri/config",
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
    "esri/widgets/BasemapGallery",
    "esri/layers/WebTileLayer",
    "esri/layers/WMSLayer",
    "esri/geometry",
    "esri/Basemap",
], function (esriConfig, Map, MapView, BasemapToggle, BasemapGallery, WebTileLayer, WMSLayer, SpatialReference, Basemap) {
    // Set the API Key 
    esriConfig.apiKey = "AAPKe1c05b9485c44780824e587fe012a020tUuqQMozRdQZiJa_DA9xrDKX6I5Dsl7F9KurI89k2tGEKbfrfdpoX6ek8Kh0rqIf";  
    
    // SST
    const layer = new WMSLayer({
        url: "https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/thredds/wms/Blended/SST5km/Night/GHRSSTOSPO/2023/20230101000000-OSPO-L4_GHRSST-SSTfnd-Geo_Polar_Blended_Night-GLOB-v02.0-fv01.0.nc", // ?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities
        sublayers: [
            {
              name: "analysed_sst",
              
            }
        ],
    });
    
    let basemap = new Basemap({
        portalItem: {
          id: "1a386c5dfd864bfda3f03ab428e57640"  // dark-gray-vector WGS84 
        }
    });
    const map = new Map({
        // Basemap for everything but SST
        basemap: basemap // "dark-gray-vector" // Basemap layer service. OG -> arcgis-topographic

        // // Basemap for the SST
        // basemap: {
        //     baseLayers: [layer]
        // }
    });
    
    
    const view = new MapView({
        map: map,
        container: "viewDiv", // Div element

        // For everything but SST
        center: [-75.056, 38.540], // Longitude, latitude
        zoom: 5, // Zoom level
        
        // // For SST.
        // spatialReference: SpatialReference.WGS84 // { wkid: 102100 } -> OG for SST
    });
    // view.extent = new Extent({
    //     xmin: -180,
    //     ymin: -90,
    //     xmax: 180,
    //     ymax: 90,
    //     spatialReference: {
    //         wkid: 4326
    //     }
    // });
    

    // // Bottom Right basemap toggle.
    // const basemapToggle = new BasemapToggle({
    //     view: view,
    //     nextBasemap: "arcgis-imagery"
    // });
    // view.ui.add(basemapToggle,"bottom-right"); // Adding the toggle switcher to the bottom right

    // // Gallery for the basemaps, but the issue is I did not see anywhere how to have it drop down!
    // const basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
    //     view: view,
    //     source: {
    //       query: {
    //         title: '"World Basemaps for Developers" AND owner:esri'
    //       }
    //     }
    // });
    // view.ui.add(basemapGallery, "top-right"); // Add to the view (off while in development)


    // This is Ocean Color from the Data Portal. 
    // const tiledLayer = new WebTileLayer({
    //     urlTemplate:
    //       "https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/socd/mecb/color/ocview/VIIRS/truecolor/2023/20231003/{z}/{y}_{x}.png",
    //     subDomains: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    // });
    // map.add(tiledLayer);  // Add to the view (off while in development)

    map.add(layer);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at the WMS parameters used in the mentioned [web site](https://coastwatch.noaa.gov/cw_html/cwViewer.html?lat=27.00&lon=-80.80&z=3&date=20231002&layer0=basemapWI&layer1=ghrsstBlendedOSPOd). Code below works for me (projection is standard web Mercator EPSG:3857):

```
const layer = new WMSLayer({
  url: "https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/thredds/wms/Blended/SST5km/Night/GHRSSTOSPO/2023/20230101000000-OSPO-L4_GHRSST-SSTfnd-Geo_Polar_Blended_Night-GLOB-v02.0-fv01.0.nc",
  sublayers: [
    {
      name: "analysed_sst"
    }
  ],
  customParameters: {
    STYLES: 'boxfill/Rainbow',
    COLORSCALERANGE: '271,310',
    FORMAT: 'image/png',
    NUMCOLORBANDS: 215
  },
});

const map = new Map({
  basemap: "dark-gray-vector",
  layers: [layer]
});
        
const view = new MapView({
  map: map,
  container: "viewDiv",
  center: [-75.056, 38.540],
  zoom: 5
});
map.add(layer);
```

This is how the result looks like then:

[image]